# converting 4 dimensional variable to 3 dimensional variable netcdf

Tags: variables, time, latitude-longitude, netcdf, dimensions

I have a netcdf data file with the following variables shown in the ncdump snippet below:

```
netcdf elev.0.5-deg {
dimensions:
    lat = 360 ;
    lon = 720 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
variables:
    float lat(lat) ;
        lat:title = "Latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:scale_factor = 1.f ;
        lat:add_offset = 0.f ;
    float lon(lon) ;
        lon:title = "Longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:scale_factor = 1.f ;
        lon:add_offset = 0.f ;
    double time(time) ;
        time:title = "Time" ;
        time:units = "hours since 1-1-1 0:0:0" ;
        time:scale_factor = 1.f ;
        time:add_offset = 0.f ;
    short data(time, lat, lon) ;
        data:long_name = "meters, from 5-min data" ;
        data:add_offset = 0.f ;
        data:scale_factor = 1.f ;
        data:missing_value = 32767s ;
        data:units = "meters, from 5-min data" ;
```

I am trying to eliminate the time coordinate variable from this file in order to get a 3 dimensional netcdf data file.  Basically having data the data values for the first time in the netcdf files and that is all.   I have tried to accomplish this with ncks which is what they showed I should do when doing a google search.  I tried the following command with ncks:

```
  ncks -x -v time elev.0.5-deg.nc test.nc
```

but I cannot get the time dimension removed.  What should I be doing to tweak this command to get the desired results of showing the data for just the initial time step and only having dimensions lat and lon in test.nc?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ncwa](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#xmp_ncwa)

```
ncwa -a time in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using CDO:

```
 cdo --reduce_dim -copy elev.0.5-deg.nc test.nc
```

Comment: in that case the file is possibly not CF-compliant